# Scala Spark contains vs. does not contain

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I can filter - as per below - tuples in an RDD using "contains". But what about filtering an RDD using "does not contain" ?

```
val rdd2 = rdd1.filter(x => x._1 contains ".")
```

I cannot find the syntax for this. Assuming it is possible and that I'm not using `DataFrame`s. I cannot see from how to do it with regex and/or filter examples.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's just the *negation* of the `contains` filter predicate :

```
val rdd2 = rdd1.filter(x => !(x._1 contains "."))
```

Comment: Thanks, a case of the forest for the trees!